# How to iterate through Lists using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a list like this, for all users issues are assigned

```
userId      issueNo     issue_desc                  comments
amit        t12334      login not happening         login via test user not happening
amit        t1666       session is not cleared      after logout session is not cleared
yash        st5436      Transaction Logs            check transaction logs
```

how can i achieve the following using JSTL?

```
amit
issueNo             issue_desc                      comments
12334               login not happening             login via test user not happening
t1666               session is not cleared          after logout session is not cleared

yash
issueNo             issue_desc                      comments
st5436              Transaction Logs                check transaction logs
```

Or is there any better way I can display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) sort list of users by 'userId';
2) use the next cycle:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>issueNo</th>
    <th>issue_desc</th>
    <th>comments</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
  <c:if test="${empty prevUser or user.userId != prevUser.userId}">
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3' align='left'><c:out value="${user.userId}"/></td>
    </tr>
  </c:if>
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${user.issueNo}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.issue_desc}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.comments}"/></td>
  </tr>
  <c:set var="prevUser" value="${user}" />
</c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hey it worked... thanks a lot buddy!!! just had to change the array index accordingly!!!